# Select remaining items from MySQL database compared to previous SELECT statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables I'm trying pull data from in 2 SELECT statements. The first one is working flawlessly, but I can't figure out what statement I need for the second.

My SELECT statement for the first is as follows:

```
SELECT * 
from prodCat 
LEFT JOIN cat ON cat.catID = prodCat.catID 
WHERE prodCat.prodID = $prodEdit
```

I then use a while loop to list out the categories that a product has. However, below that, I want to populate a select box with the categories that are NOT attributed to the product. I tried the following:

```
SELECT * 
from prodCat 
LEFT JOIN cat ON cat.catID = prodCat.catID 
WHERE prodCat.prodID != $prodEdit
```

But that did not work. Does anyone know what I could try to accomplish this?

I'm working with PHP to access a MySQL database.

Comment: Please explain *"does not work"*.

Answer (score 3):

This query shoud work:

```
SELECT * FROM cat WHERE catID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT catID FROM prodCat)
```

first we list all category ID from `prodCat` (this is the subrequest on the right), then we select all category with ID not in the first list.

Comment: So after trying this solution out, it looks like it conflicts with other records. If one product is associated with a category, that category will no longer be listed for other products. It seems the hiding is universal and not for each product.

Comment: Just add a where to the subquery?

Comment: Thanks! I added: WHERE prodCat.prodID = $prodEdit and it works PERFECTLY!

Answer (score 0):

You may be better off running 1 query to return the result of all categories, identifying if the category is associated or not (also sorted by that value). In your PHP iterate through the 1 result set to load both select boxes.

```
SELECT cat.*, IF(prodCat.catID IS NULL,'No','Yes') AS related
FROM cat
LEFT JOIN prodCAT
  ON cat.catID = prodCat.catID
    AND prodCat.prodID = $prodEdit
ORDER BY related DESC;
```